# Why don't some top-end single-actuator disk drives use more than one head at a time to read or write data?

Tags: hard-drive, performance, throughput

I was watching this talk [1] where two engineers from Seagate were presenting their findings of using their newly-developed MACH.2 multi-actuator drives [2] as part of ZFS pools. In some cases, they were measuring about twice the IPOS per second as well as twice the throughput.

During the Q/A-Section, there was one question asked, which I found quite interesting (at 25:57 in the video at [1]). The person asking the question noted that, by their understanding, these new drives only doubled the number of actuators (groups of heads that move together) from 1 to 2 while the number of heads stayed constant and that this should only maybe explain a doubling in IPOS but not a doubling in throughput. The explanation given was that in traditional drives, with a single actuator, only one head is active at a time and used for reading or writing while in their new drive, one head for each actuator can be active at the same time.

This last fact surprises me greatly. Considering that allowing multiple heads to be active at the same time could increase read and write throughput by a large factor, it seems that there must be almost insurmountable obstacles in building a disk drive with this capability.

What are these obstacles? And are there examples where this has nonetheless been achieved?

[1]: [Multi-Actuator HDDs by Muhammad Ahmad & James Borden](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IpIzKmnvktU)

[2]: [Multi Actuator Technology: A New Performance Breakthrough](https://blog.seagate.com/craftsman-ship/multi-actuator-technology-a-new-performance-breakthrough/)

Comment: I’m going to go out on a limb here and say it was an error in their explanation. Of course the drive can use multiple heads at a time. However, if the data it is seeking is not stored on the same track on all platters then less than the entire set of heads will be able to read data at one time. If there are two independent head groups then two heads are always guaranteed to be able to read independent tracks at the same time, could be more.

Comment: @Appleoddity If your explanation is correct, that multiple heads are used when data to be read or written is at the same location on multiple platters, then I don't understand how they got a 2x improvement of _sequential_ reads and writes by adding a second actuator. Assuming of course that they would already have made the most of their single-actuator drives by arranging the LBAs in such a way that sequential IO lands on the same locations on all platters.

Comment: @Chenmunka There is one answer listing reasons agains building such drives, without saying whether they actually exist, one answer which cites a passage from wikipedia which since has been removed from the cited article and another answer arguing why it's hard to build such drives without answering the question. So no. :/

Answer (score 0):

> Considering that allowing multiple heads to be active at the same time ...

Your premise is not a trivial matter.  You seem to subscribe to the "more is better" fallacy.

First, the read/write head is just one component in the HDD that is involved in actually reading and writing data from/to the platter surface.
There are analog (amplifiers, equalizers) and digital (encoders/decoders, shifters, ECC logic) circuits in between the sector buffer holding the data and the R/W head that are also involved.
When only one R/W head is used (at a time), a simple multiplexer can be used to connect the selected R/W head to the R/W electronics.
In order to have *"multiple heads ... active at the same time"* there would have to be a set of R/W electronics replicated for each active R/W head.
There are power, space, and economic ramifications of using more than one R/W head.

Second is the question of how and/or when more than one R/W head could be simultaneously utilized.
The probability that the HDD has consistently more pending operations on *different tracks* but in the *same cylinder* is not likely to be so high that the added complexity and cost of additional R/W electronics can be justified.

> it seems that there must be almost insurmountable obstacles in building a disk drive with this capability.

There could actually be a technical reason for only one active R/W head per actuator.  One possibility could be how the servo feedback operates for the actuator.

> What are these obstacles?

One such *"obstacle"* is probably economic.

Operationally the opportunities to fully utilize multiple active R/W heads on one actuator are not good with conventional drive configuration (i.e. sector order on a track has precedence over head order).  To take advantage of multiple active R/W heads, head order could have precedence over sector order for "sequential" sectors.

> And are there examples where this has nonetheless been achieved?

Historically the complexity and cost of the disk controller and R/W electronics has constrained HDDs to use a single active R/W head per actuator.
However dual-actuator drives are not new at all, and date back (at least) to the 1980s.  Obviously those drives were not 5.25", 3.5" or 2.5" form factor, but rather floor standing.  These were dual-ported drives, meaning that the actuators operated independently of each other, and it was up to the disk controllers (and/or host computer/filesystem) for each port to coordinate and resolve contentious/conflicting disk operations.

There have also been other dual-actuator drives in the 5.25" and/or 3.5" form factor.
Note that the Seagate drive you cite is a single-port drive but exposes two LUNs.  So the host computer/OS effectively sees two logical drives.

Comment: Thank you very much for you answer. But I feel that you missed the point almost completely. Let me refute your argument step by step:

Comment: _"In order to have "multiple heads ... active at the same time" there would have to be a set of R/W electronics replicated for each active R/W head."_ -- I'll argue that all the components you listed are being produced in form factors that have been scaled down by multiple orders of magnitude since the 3.5 inch form-factor was introduced. Power consumption of these components has also been reduced by at least a factor of 10. If multiple instances of those electronics did not fit into a single drive enclosure then, they would today.

Comment: Also, the MACH.2 drives from the talk I linked, Seagate actually managed to include two instances of those components, as well as two instances of the components necessary to move the heads independently (motors, motor drivers, sensors, …).

Comment: _"The probability that the HDD has consistently more pending operations on different tracks but in the same cylinder is not likely to be so high that the added complexity and cost of additional R/W electronics can be justified."_ -- In simple sequential IO scenarios (which the Seagate engineers tested and presented in their talk), this would exactly be the case. Blocks are written in the same order as they are read so arranging them in the right way on the platter would allow all heads to be used for both operations.

Comment: I'm assuming that sequential IO is an important use-case for at least some of Seagate's high-end customers, partly because they said exactly that and partly because using more smaller-sized disks (which has the down size of more resource usage in terms of space, power, disk shelves and SAS ports) is sometimes preferred to larger disks because of the higher throughput (sequential IO performance) of the former.

Comment: _"There could actually be a technical reason for only one active R/W head per actuator. One possibility could be how the servo feedback operates for the actuator."_ -- This is the only rational explanation I could imagine before posting my question. But I was unable to find sources supporting this theory. If this is the case, I would like to know more about it.

Comment: _"One such "obstacle" is probably economic. Operationally the opportunities to fully utilize multiple active R/W heads on one actuator are not good with conventional drive configuration"_ -- I don't understand. What is the obstacle here? In the next sentence you suggest that the sector order could actually be changed, which seems reasonably considering that these mechanisms are implemented in software on the drive's controller.

Comment: _"However dual-actuator drives are not new at all, and date back (at least) to the 1980s."_ -- I think my question _"And are there examples where this has nonetheless been achieved?"_ was misunderstood here. My question was about drives using more than one head simultaneously on a single actuator. Sorry for the confusion, I edited the question to make this clearer.